# Casting from cv::Vec2d to cv::Vec2i through ceil/floor

Tags: c++, opencv, casting

I'd need to either ceil- or floor-off an OpenCV vector of doubles.

With the following code, I got a conversion performed through **rounding**:

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cv::Vec2d v(1.3, 1.3);
    cout << v[0] << ";" << v[1] << endl;
    cv::Vec2i vi = cv::Vec2i(v);

    cout << vi[0] << ";" << vi[1] << endl; // Print "1;1"

    v = cv::Vec2d(1.7,1.7);
    vi = cv::Vec2i(v);
    cout << vi[0] << ";" << vi[1] << endl; // Print "2;2"
    return 0;
}
```

How could I **directly** obtain a conversion to an integer vector through ceiling (`Print "2;2"` in both cases) or flooring (`Print "1;1"` in both cases)? By *directly* I mean without the need for a loop to access each element.

Comment: what do you mean? that's exactly what happens. the entire vector is converted at once. your per-element output has nothing to do with the conversion. your example contains no loops.

Comment: Sorry, maybe now it's more clear. The default conversion is, as expected, a round operation. As per the question title, I'd like to know if the conversation could be achieved through a ceil or floor operation instead

Comment: `cv::Vec2i(cvCeil(v[0]), cvCeil[v1])` and similar for floor. If you want it generic to handle other sizes of `Vec`, write a simple templated function that calls `cvCeil/cvFloor` in a loop -- just like the [`operator()`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/matx.hpp#L1140) you're currently using does with a `saturate_cast`. (Not sure why you consider a loop undesireable, it's not like the compiler won't unroll something this trivial).

Comment: strangely, OpenCV doesn't appear to have (I can't find in the docs) functions for ceil()/floor(), not even for cv::Mat, and I can't find methods on Mat or Vec either. it has more complex stuff like log10() though... perhaps worth opening a feature request for this.